# How to change colours of text & lines in header rows/columns in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: colors, libreoffice, gtk3, user-interface

In LibreOffice Calc, how does one change the colours  of the text in the header rows and columns?  I'm referring to the "A", "B", "C", ... and "1", "2", "3" ... as in the screenshot below.

Also, how does one change the colours of the lines within each header (not referring to grid lines within the spreadsheet itself)?

They are too bright for my preference. Distro is Linux Mint.

[image: LibreOffice Calc screenshot with arrows pointing to the row and column headers]

Comment: It appears to be driven from your desktop theme colours. I can't test though, so not an answer